# How detailed a construction of the family tree of known human fossils do we have?

Tags: taxonomy, phylogenetics, human-evolution

For the sake of this question, by "human" I mean Hominina. The best I could find is [this](http://humanorigins.si.edu/evidence/human-family-tree), which isn't very detailed. Of the dozens of paleospecies we'd seek to link up, do we have a more detailed tree attempt? Of course, it would be provisional and approximate, and the details would be somewhat debated; but I'm trying to gauge how fuzzy it is with our current knowledge.